# Intuition Behind Correlation Function in Kriging Models

Tags: correlation, gaussian-process, intuition, interpolation, kriging

I'm thinking and researching extensively to interpret the parameter $\theta$ (activeness parameter) in Gaussian correlation function in a Kriging model, namely as:
$$
K(h;\theta)=exp(-h^2/(2\theta^2))
$$
or in some literatures:
$$
K(h;\theta)=exp(-\theta h^2)
$$

The random variables are correlated with each other using the basis function expression:

$$
cor[Y(x^{(j)}),Y(x^{(l)})]=exp(-\sum_{i=1}^k\theta_i|x_i^{(j)}-x_i^{(l)}|^2)
$$

I know this parameter $\theta_i$ represents the activeness of each feature $x_i, i=1,...k$ where $k$ is the number of features.
My question here is, after we estimate this $\theta$ for each feature, how do we **interpret** this parameter $\theta$ for every feature in the first and second equation? For example, if we find $\theta_{x_1} = 10$ for $x_1$, what does 10 mean here?

Comment: What is the meaning of the subscript $i$ and how do you suppose the $\theta_i$ are related to $\theta$?

Comment: $i$ refers to $i$th feature in data.

Comment: @whuber I updated my question to clarify how $\theta$ relates to $\theta_i$.

Comment: This blog post gives some helpful intuition. https://yugeten.github.io/posts/2019/09/GP/

Comment: This [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-do-i-interpret-the-length-scale-parameter-of-the-rbf-kernel) has some relevant information about the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take your second formulation:

$$K(h;\theta)=exp(-\theta h^2)$$

The overall intuition is that $h$ is represents the distance between two points. It is always non-negative.

As $\theta$ multiplies $h$, the larger $\theta$ is the more negative $-\theta h^2$ becomes.

The more negative the exponent becomes, the smaller $K$ becomes.

Therefore, increasing $\theta$ makes your 'correlation' drop to zero more quickly the further apart the points are.

You'd have to do a similar walkthrough for each formulation, depending on signs, whether $\theta$ divides or multiplies etc.

But note for the third formulation that, holding $x_i^{(k)}, i>1, k \in \{j,l\}$ constant, the equation could be written:

$$K = exp(-\sum_{i=1}^k\theta_i|x_i^{(j)}-x_i^{(l)}|^2) = exp(-\theta_1 (x_1^{(j)}-x_1^{(l)})^2) c = exp(-\theta_1 h_1^2) c $$

Which again has the above interpretation.

Comment: Thank you "@conjectures" for your response. I can follow how $\theta$ would affect the correlation between samples. What I cannot infer is to relate $\theta$ value to each feature. Since in Kriging, $\theta$ is the activeness parameter which I cannot interpret it intuitively. For example, if we find $\theta_{x_1} = 10$ for $x_1$, what does 10 mean here?

Comment: Exactly the same interpretation applies as above, but *holding the other elements constant*. That's why I picked your second formulation rather than your first ;) Anyway, added a comment.

Comment: So can we say, as $\theta_i$ becomes larger, the corresponding variable $x_i$ encourages the points to be more uncorrelated, given other variables constant?

Comment: > 'the corresponding variable xi'.  Actually the distance between the $i^{th}$ elements of a pair of points $x^{(j)}, x^{(l)}$

Comment: Can you please elaborate more your last comment? I did not get what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: Well it's not the size of the $x$s, it's the distance between them that matters. |3 - 1| = 2, |1000 - 999| = 1.